# mysql Trigger to prevent entry being written to a table AFTER writing to another table

Tags: mysql, trigger, mysql-8.0

Is there a way to use `SIGNAL` in a trigger to prevent a query being written to a table, but only **AFTER** you have logged the details in another table?

for example:

```
CREATE TABLE `test2` (
  `txtvals` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
);

CREATE TABLE `log2` (
  `txtvals` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
);

DROP TRIGGER tr_test2;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER tr_test2
BEFORE INSERT ON test2
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.txtvals IN ('a','b','c') THEN
    INSERT INTO `log2` (`txtvals`)
        VALUES (NEW.`txtvals`);

    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '02000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Warning: Message Dropped from test2';

    END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;


insert into test2 (`txtvals`) values ('a');

select * from test2;
select * from log2;
```

When I run the Inert into test2 I get the error I expect:

`Error Code: 1643. Warning: Message Dropped from test2`

but there is nothing in log2.

Comment: Non-solvable by this way. SIGNAL in the trigger results in the whole transaction rollback. So all changes made by both the trigger and the query which causes this trigger firing are rollbacked. You must use stored procedure with needed logic instead of the trigger.

Comment: ok cheers. I assumed this was going to be the case, but wanted to check I hadn't missed something.